# How do I remove SVG from a Fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

So I've deduced that I can add SVG graphics to the canvas by using:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('img1.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var obj1 = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(obj1);
}); 

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('img2.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var obj2 = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(obj2);
});
```

Suppose I now want to delete one or both of those. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `fabricjs` I use different method to delete object in canvas. this method delete any object in canvas. `fabricjs` allow to set `name` for each object so we can use this property to delete object.like this (i use jquery for this:)

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('test.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var obj2 = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    obj2.name ="test_svg"   //<<<<<<< here set name
    canvas.add(obj2);
    console.log(canvas.getObjects())
}); 

function del(){
$.each(canvas._objects, function(index, obj) {
     if(obj == null) return;
     $.each(obj, function(attr, value) {
          //console.log( attr + ' == ' + value );
             if(value == "test_svg"){ //<<<<< here we call name
                   //alert(index);
                     canvas.remove(canvas._objects[index]); // here we delete that object
                     canvas.renderAll();
                 }
             });
});
}
```

I test this from load svg method and its worked.so maybe this is worked for you ..