# How to remove only images from canavas?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to remove images from canvas by remaining svg template on fabricjs canvas. `canvas.clear();` remove all the stuff on canvas. But I need to keep svg template itself. How to do this?

Comment: @Kaiido Simply I need to remove previous image when I add a new image to the canvas.

Comment: At the end of this paragraph http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#groups the [`remove()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#remove) method is what you want

Comment: This answer will help you ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256147/how-do-i-remove-svg-from-a-fabric-js-canvas/36256858#36256858)